# one set of yelp api access keys for multiple sites? keys work for one not the other

Tags: api, key, yelp

I have two sites both using the same yelp api access keys.  Is that ok?  in fact when I run both sites off the same  dev box - ie same IP - the keys work for one site but not the other.  Also , the keys work on dev for that site but not for the live site - any reason to do with the API or   just a bug on my end?  If I need multiple access keys how do I  get them as the manage api access seems to only allow me one set at a time.

when they fail I get this error  on   dev :
Array ( [error] => Array ( [text] => Signature was invalid [id] => INVALID_SIGNATURE [description] => Invalid signature. Expected signature base string: GET....

tracing thought my code has not revealed any differences in the code or the calls to yelp yet, in fact I just copied the code over from the functional site's folders.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

upon further testing with other searches it turns out that I get the error mentioned when the saerch fails, but sometimes I get results and no error.  So the error message is very misleading.  The sig is valid.

But in order to work for a  business call the business id must first be url encoded - I found that on ids that contained accented characters it was failing but not on others.  I guess that closes this issue.